# Java reg-ex to get tokens?

Tags: java, regex

```
samplefile.html.xml[emailaddress@gmail.com],samplefile.html.xml[emailaddress@gmail.com]
```

What is the reg-ex to gather file and email address as 2 tokens in java?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you expect the "file" and "email address" to be?

Comment: 1st step would be to split the entire string using (,). After you get the token, check for the existence of the [ and  ]  and get their index and get sub-strings accordingly...but i am looking for reg-ex, which i guess is not my area!

Comment: `split()` sounds just fine to me. Why do you need a regex?

Comment: Split would be first step and then i need to separate out the part within braces and outside braces for each of the split items! Was wondering if reg-ex would be of better help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
(?:([^\[]*?)\[(.*?)\],?)+?
```

As a Java String:

```
"(?:([^\\[]*?)\\[(.*?)\\],?)+?"
```